# xamarin picker SelectedItem returning null on observable collection

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, picker

in my xamarin project, picker binding, the SelectedItem is not working.  When I have the ItemSource set to a List, the SelectedItem works, but when I change the ItemSource to an ObservableCollection, the SelectedItem always returns null.  Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

on loading the view, the pickers are populated through databinding.  then on a button event I try and grab the SelectedItem.... which is when it is coming back as null.

xaml

```
        <Picker x:Name="PickerMarket2" Title="Market2" ClassId="PickerMarket2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TestList2}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ShortDesc}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMarket}"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
        </Picker>
```

view model

```
    class VamiMarketViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<string> _testList;
    public List<string> TestList
    {
        get { return _testList; }
        set
        {
            {
                _testList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Performance> _testList2;
    public ObservableCollection<Performance> TestList2
    {
        get { return _testList2; }
        set
        {
            {
                _testList2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _selectedMarket;
    public string SelectedMarket
    {
        get { return _selectedMarket; }
        set
        {
            {
                _selectedMarket = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this exact issue was just explained to you on your previous question.  Your ItemSource is a List<Performance> but your SelectedItem is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just explained the same in your [other question here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#populating-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding).

To what I see from your code, the `SelectedItem` seems to be the problem. 
Since your `Picker`'s `ItemsSource`(TestList property) is of type `List<Performance>`, the `SelectedItem` property bound to the `Picker` must be of type `Performance`. But, in your case, you have kept it as `string` instead of `Performance`.

The `ItemDisplayBinding` must be the name of any property inside your `Performance` object which in your case is fine since you have a string property called `ShortDesc` inside your `Performance` class.

That's the problem I see in your code. Change the type of the property `ShortDesc` like below and assign any one of the items in your collection `TestList` to it. Your code will start working fine.

```
private Performance _shortDesc;
public Performance ShortDesc
{
   get { return _shortDesc; } 
   set
   {
       {
            _shortDesc = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
       }
   }
}
```

> Refer to the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#populating-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding) which explains a clear example for Binding objects to Picker.

I hope that helps.